# Web API Microservice implementation not performing as expected when calling services in parallel

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, parallel-processing, async-await

I have a .NET Web-API service that is calling one to many other services. In this scenario I'm not sure if using Task.Run is the right approach. I've read other questions which have stated that using this is not the best approach, but if I want to run a process in parallel to ensure the most efficient calls I can't think of a better approach.

```
        var membershipPersons = Task.Run(() => MembershipPersonsRepository.GetMembershipPersonsAsync(
            new Dictionary<string, object>() {
                { "membershipId", membershipId},
                { "asAt", "Current"}}, 1));
```

Once I have made a call to the service above, I believe I need to wait for it to complete before I'm able to use the results, though perhaps my understanding of ContinueWith is incorrect as the first example seems to work, however the 2nd example doesn't.

```
        await Task.WhenAll(membershipPersons).ContinueWith(            
        (
            mpt =>
            {
                if (mpt.IsFaulted)
                    throw membershipPersons.Exception.InnerException;
```

This code does appear to correctly call multiple membershipPersons at once which is what I'm expecting.

```
               //Get all Person Address details derived from Mem Persons
                var personAddressesTasks = membershipPersons.Result.Select(ps => Task.Run(() => PersonAddressesRepository.GetPersonAddressesAsync(
                        new Dictionary<string, object>(){
                            { "personId", ps.PersonId}, }, 1))).ToList();
```

IIS appears to crash at this stage on a Windows 10 machine, I'm unsure if this is due to a connection limitation. With approximately 5 membershipPersons this appears to work fine over and over, however for 10 or more this continually fails and forces me to do an IIS restart.

```
                Task.WhenAll(personAddressesTasks).ContinueWith(
                async p =>
                {
```

I'm unsure if the next section is the correct approach. It's based of a Pluralsight course that Jon Skeet presented, though that was entirely based on a windows client using Async Await. Web API appears to just skip past this code without waiting for it to complete which causes an issue when I try and consume the services.

```
                    foreach (var task in personAddressesTasks)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            if (task.IsCompleted)
                            {
                                var personAddressTask = await task;

                                var personAddress = personAddressTask?.FirstOrDefault();

                                if (personAddress != null)
                                    personAddresses.Add(personAddress);
                            }
                            if (task.IsFaulted)
                                throw task.Exception;
                        }
                        catch (AggregateException e)
                        {
                            throw e.InnerException;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        ));
        // Populate response entity.
```

EDIT 1:

Running the above was causing IIS to crash with 10 or more personAddress calls being run in parallel. Running sequentially like this seems to not cause an issue, even though it's still almost instantaneous to run.

```
        var membershipPersons = Task.Run(() => MembershipPersonsRepository.GetMembershipPersons(
            new Dictionary<string, object>() {
                { "membershipId", membershipId},
                { "asAt", "Current"}}, 1));

Task.WaitAll(membershipPersons);

        foreach (var mp in membershipPersons.Result)
        {
            var pa = await PersonAddressesRepository.GetPersonAddresses(
              new Dictionary<string, object>(){
                    { "personId", mp.PersonId}, }, 1);

            personAddresses.AddRange(pa);
        };
```

Using only Await and no Task.Run certainly caused my set of calls to only run sequentially. So have stuck with Task.Run with no await.

I'd still like to identify if this is a suitable method in WebAPI and why IIS is crashing with a parallel call of 10 request.

Comment: If `GetMembershipPersonsAsync` already returns a `Task` - why do you need to wrap it in `Task.Run`?

Comment: What I haven't shown here is there along with GetMembershipPersonAsync, I have 4 other calls which I wanted to run in Parallel, which is why my thinking was putting each in a task would make it do that.

Comment: But they already return `Task`, not? Can you show `GetMembershipPersonsAsync` signature?

Comment: I'll just play around with it taking out the Task.Run and see how it goes, you are right that await returns a task so hopefully it'll work as you've indicated.

Comment: @Zintah can you clarify what you mean by "parallel"? Do you mean on separate "threads" or actually in parallel across multiple cores? Could you also please post the entirety of the code that you're trying to get to work, rather than a number of disparate boxes?